# avoid blank line when reading names from .txt into python list

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I'm trying read a list of names from a .txt file into python so I can work with it.

```
humans = ['Barry', 'Finn', 'John', 'Jacob', '', 'George', 'Ringo', '']

with open(p_to_folder / 'humans.txt', 'w') as f:#using pathlib for my paths
    for h in humans:
        f.write(f'{h}\n')
```

What I'd like to do is read the .txt file back in so that I can work with names again, but leave out the blanks.

I have tried

```
with open(p_to_folder / 'humans.txt', 'r') as f:#using pathlib for my paths
    new_humans = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines() if line != '']
```

when I inspect this is list I get

```
['Barry', 'Finn', 'John', 'Jacob', '', 'George', 'Ringo', '']
```

I can just run the line

```
new_humans = [i for i in new_humans if i != '']
```

and get

```
['Barry', 'Finn', 'John', 'Jacob', 'George', 'Ringo']
```

but I'd like to be able to do it in one line, and also to understand why my if statement isn't working in the original list comprehension.

Thank you

Comment: The rstripped line doesn't equal the empty string, not line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
with open(p_to_folder / 'humans.txt', 'r+') as f:#using pathlib for my paths
    new_humans  = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
```

Comment: Thank you, if you have a minute can you explain why `line.strip()` works and my `line != ''` didn't? It's something to do with what `line.strip()` produces I assume?

Comment: @KevOMalley743 `line.strip()` removes extra spaces from the string. For example, if the string is `s = '     '` then `s.strip()` returns an empty string `''`. you can use `line.strip() != ''` this will also work but it is unnecessary. Because an empty string is equal to `False` already.

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like this:

```py
with open(p_to_folder / 'humans.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_humans = [line for line in f.read().splitlines() if line]
```

Or:

```py
with open(p_to_folder / 'humans.txt', 'r') as f:#using pathlib for my paths
    new_humans = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line != '\n']
```

Output:

```
['Barry', 'Finn', 'John', 'Jacob', 'George', 'Ringo']
```